# How to shorten (format) String output properly?

Tags: java, string, output

Simple questions as a beginner making big problems.

I want to shorten (format) a String to only show 1 decimal or 2. Unlucky it is a String not a double.

```
String getNumber = "6.000m";
```

I know there is a printf() function but as far I learned it is to print multiple string in a proper order.

How can I make the output to be with only one decimal or if it has more numbers which aren't 0?

```
6.000 m --> 6.0
4.900 m --> 4.9
4.750 m --> 4.75
```

Comment: There's no existing function that'll do exactly what you want. You'll need to parse the string, pull out the number, and print it back out in the desired format.

Comment: Is your string always in the format of "<some number>m"?

Comment: yes it's always on the format of "<x.xxx> m"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is always "m" at the end with some optional whitespace in front of it. So I remove it first using a regex. 
DecimalFormat is your friend to do the rest:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Ff {
    static Pattern numberPart=Pattern.compile("([0-9.]*)\\b*m");
    static DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.0#####");

    public static String format(String input)
    {
        Matcher m=numberPart.matcher(input);
        if(m.matches())
        {
            return df.format(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)));
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(format("6.000m"));
        System.out.println(format("4.900m"));
        System.out.println(format("4.750m"));
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
6.0
4.9
4.75
```

Comment: Note: It's better to put the array brackets behind the type instead of the variable name, i.e. `String[] args` instead of `String args[]`.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use regex, because it is very hard to maintain.

As an example:

```
    (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01- 
    \x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?: 
    (?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0- 
    5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]| 
    [1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\ 
    [\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

This is a part of some code to validate an email with a regex. Regexes were necessary back then when computers were slow, because regexes are fast. Nowadays you don't need them anymore and maintenance is key.

After using the test cases:

- 0.000 m -> 0.0
- 1.000 m -> 1.0
- 9.000 m -> 9.0
- 1.100 m -> 1.1
- 1.900 m -> 1.9
- 1.110 m -> 1.11
- 1.010 m -> 1.01
- 1.111 m -> 1.111
- 1.101 m -> 1.101
- 1.101m  -> 1.101

I've come to this conclusion:

`shortenGivenNumber(String wholeNumber);` will be the Method you'll use to shorten your number. The other methods are there to make the main method more readable.

```
public class NumberShortener {

    public String shortenGivenNumber(String wholeNumber) {
        int endOfShortNumber = findEndOfNumber(wholeNumber);
        
        String shortenedNumber = cutOutNumber(wholeNumber, endOfShortNumber);
            
        return shortenedNumber;
    }

    private int findEndOfNumber(String numberWithZeroesAndM) {
        int lastZero = findIndexOfZeroAfterNumber(numberWithZeroesAndM);
        
        int endOfNumber = lastZero;
        
        endOfNumber = handleNo0AtEndCase(numberWithZeroesAndM, lastZero, endOfNumber);
        
        return endOfNumber;
    }

    private int findIndexOfZeroAfterNumber(String wholeNumber) {
        int lastZero; 

        int searchIndex = 3;
        boolean numberAfterZero;
        do {
            numberAfterZero = false;
            
            lastZero = findNextIndexOfZero(wholeNumber, searchIndex);
            numberAfterZero = isANumberAfterThisZero(wholeNumber, lastZero);
            
            searchIndex++;
        }while(numberAfterZero == true && valueExistsAtEnd(lastZero));
        
        return lastZero;
    }

    private int findNextIndexOfZero(String wholeNumber, int searchIndex) {
        return wholeNumber.indexOf("0", searchIndex);
    }

    private boolean isANumberAfterThisZero(String wholeNumber, int lastZero) {
        boolean numberAfterZero = false;
        
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            char characterAfterZero = getCharacterAfterZero(wholeNumber, lastZero);
            char iAsChar = convertIntToChar(i);
            
            if(isTheCharacterThisNumber(characterAfterZero, iAsChar)){
                numberAfterZero = true;
            }
        }
        return numberAfterZero;
    }
    

    private boolean valueExistsAtEnd(int lastZero) {
        return lastZero != -1;
    }

    private int handleNo0AtEndCase(String wholeNumber, int lastZero, int endOfNumber) {
        if(thisSignIsntAtEnd(lastZero)){
            int indexOfSpace = getIndexOfSpace(wholeNumber);
            endOfNumber = indexOfSpace;
            endOfNumber = handleNoSpaceAtEndCase(wholeNumber, endOfNumber, indexOfSpace);
        }
        return endOfNumber;
    }

    private int getIndexOfSpace(String wholeNumber) {
        return wholeNumber.indexOf(" ");
    }

    private int handleNoSpaceAtEndCase(String wholeNumber, int endOfNumber, int space) {
        if(thisSignIsntAtEnd(space)) {
            int indexOfM = getIndexOfM(wholeNumber);
            endOfNumber = indexOfM;
        }
        return endOfNumber;
    }

    private int getIndexOfM(String wholeNumber) {
        return wholeNumber.indexOf("m");
    }

    private char getCharacterAfterZero(String wholeNumber, int indexOfZero) {
        int indexAfterZero = indexOfZero+1;
        return wholeNumber.charAt(indexAfterZero);
    }
    

    private char convertIntToChar(int i) {
        return (char) (i+48);
    }

    private String cutOutNumber(String wholeNumber, int endOfNumber) {
        return wholeNumber.substring(0, endOfNumber);
    }

    private boolean isTheCharacterThisNumber(char characterAfterZero, char iAsChar) {
        return characterAfterZero == iAsChar;
    }
}
```

It always copies the first 3 characters(x.x). The first 0 (after the x.x), without any number following, will be used as the last index which indicates the end of the final number substring. If there are numbers over 0 until the end, it will use the space (1.123 m). If there isn't a space, it will use the m (1.123m).

Comment: I'm not convinced your code is easier to maintain than 10 lines of code with a regex.

Comment: it is actually. more code and more methods isn't bad. If you e.g. wanted to use a "-" instead of a space:

Comment: you can find the "-" very easially